# Highcharter : tooltip on second serie and shifted scatter

Tags: r, highcharts

I have two series to print on my chart: a boxplot and the points of this boxplot as a scatter plot around each boxplot.

I have 2 issues with this code :

- first, I add a personnal tooltip for the boxplot with the hc_tooltip(formatter=...) part. It works well. I add the scatter data with hc_add_series in which I add a tooltip only for this scatter. Running this code shows the same format for the scatter tooltip than the boxplot tooltip. How to have a specific tooltip for the scatter serie ???
- second, I plot the scatter with a jitter. It works well BUT the points are right to first boxplot, just as I want in the middle for the middle boxplot and are left to the last boxplot. Why is there this shift on xaxis ?

Thanx

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)
library(gapminder)

ds <- gapminder %>%
  dplyr::filter(year == 2007) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(-pop)

myboxplotData <- data_to_boxplot(
  ds,
  lifeExp,
  continent,
  group_var     = continent,
  add_outliers  = FALSE,
  fillColor     = c("red", "green","yellow", "pink","blue"),
  color        = "black",                        
)

highchart()%>%
  hc_chart(
    events = list(
      load = JS("function () {
        Highcharts.each(this.series, function (series) {
          series.legendSymbol.attr({ fill: series.options.fillColor });
        });
      }")
    )
  ) %>%
  hc_xAxis(type ="category") %>%
  hc_add_series_list(myboxplotData) %>%
  hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "continent")) %>%
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Life expectancy")) %>%
  hc_title(text= "Boxplot using highcharter") %>% 
  hc_legend(enabled= TRUE) %>%
  hc_tooltip(formatter = JS("function(){
    return ('<strong>' +
          'Continent : ' + this.series.name +
          '<br>Maximum : ' + this.series.data[0].high +
          '<br>Minimum : ' + this.series.data[0].low +
          '</strong>'
  ) }")) %>%
  hc_add_series(
      data = ds,
      type = "scatter",
      hcaes(x = "continent", y = "lifeExp", group = "continent"),
      tooltip = list(pointFormat = "X: {point.lifeExp}")
  ) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(scatter = list(
    color = "grey",
    showInLegend = FALSE,
    marker = list(
      radius = 6,
      symbol = "circle",
      lineWidth = 2
    )
  )) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(scatter = list(jitter = list(x = 0.05, y = 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is happening because the tooltip formatter you have defined at a chart level is overwriting the tooltip format for the scatter series. Instead, you could define tooltips for each series separately to customize them.

For your second issue, the jittering appears to be a known issue in Highcharts when used with boxplots, and unfortunately, there isn't a straightforward fix for this issue.

You can try the following workaround, where we add the tooltips in the series list itself and remove the chart level tooltip:

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)
library(gapminder)

ds <- gapminder %>%
  dplyr::filter(year == 2007) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(-pop)

myboxplotData <- data_to_boxplot(
  ds,
  lifeExp,
  continent,
  group_var     = continent,
  add_outliers  = FALSE,
  fillColor     = c("red", "green","yellow", "pink","blue"),
  color        = "black",                        
)

# Add tooltip to each series
myboxplotData <- lapply(myboxplotData, function(s) {
  s$tooltip <- list(
    headerFormat = paste0('<span style="font-size: 10px">', s$name, '</span><br/>'),
    pointFormat = '<strong>Continent : {series.name}<br/>Maximum : {point.high}<br/>Minimum : {point.low}</strong>'
  )
  s
})

highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(
    events = list(
      load = JS("function () {
        Highcharts.each(this.series, function (series) {
          series.legendSymbol.attr({ fill: series.options.fillColor });
        });
      }")
    )
  ) %>%
  hc_xAxis(type ="category") %>%
  hc_add_series_list(myboxplotData) %>%
  hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "continent")) %>%
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Life expectancy")) %>%
  hc_title(text= "Boxplot using highcharter") %>% 
  hc_legend(enabled= TRUE) %>%
  hc_add_series(
      data = ds,
      type = "scatter",
      hcaes(x = "continent", y = "lifeExp", group = "continent"),
      tooltip = list(pointFormat = "Life Expectancy: {point.y}")
  ) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(scatter = list(
    color = "grey",
    showInLegend = FALSE,
    marker = list(
      radius = 6,
      symbol = "circle",
      lineWidth = 2
    )
  )) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(scatter = list(jitter = list(x = 0.05, y = 0)))
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer, unfortunately your code throw an error in my terminal while adding tooltip to each series: "Error in s$name : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors". Trying to deal with it, no success at this moment...

Comment: An other point is that I used formatter function in order not to have the series name printed by default in the tooltip...How to do this with your solution ?

Comment: It worked fine for me but I think that issue may arise because the lapply function is not correctly identifying the list elements where it should apply the function to add tooltips - in your code. We can avoid this by specifying the correct level at which to apply the function. A quick way to do this is by using a for loop instead of lapply. But I'm a bit lost now about what this tooltip should look like for different series - could you explain more precisely which part for which series we want to get rid of? So you want to get rid of the country name for all series?

Comment: Thanx, yes I tried with a for loop and it works. But the country name still appears in the head of the tooltip. As you says, yes "So you want to get rid of the country name for all series?". I saw that I need to use the "formatter" function inside hc_tooltip and hc_tooltip is related to the whole chart, not for each serie !

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Well yes, for all series you can do it with hc_tooltip, simple example: 
hc_tooltip(formatter = JS(
     "function() {
       return 'Value: ' + this.y;
     }"
   ))

Comment: But then it can be corrupted for boxplot. So I think it's better to build tooltip separately from tooltip.pointFormatter, simple example: 
hc_add_series(
     type = "scatter",
     date = date_scatter,
     name = "Scatter Series",
     tooltip = list(pointFormatter = JS(
       "function() {
           return 'Scatter series value: ' + this.y;
         }"
       ))
   )

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried to add pointFormatter in tooltip in the hc_add_series part as you said above but it doesnt works, the boxplot format still overide the scatter format !

Comment: I really want to help you make it work.
Let's take a look at this simplified example in JS first:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/eL85qchg/

There are 2 formatting for scatter and boxplot. Could you describe on the basis of this example how you would like the tooltip to look for boxplot and for scatter?
Then I'll rewrite it into JS and then implement it in R.

Comment: Thanx for your help, I really appreciate. Your jsfiddle exemple is a good one and you can see the issue : the tooltip in the boxplot is EXACTLY what is defined in the headerFormat and printFormat section BUT the tooltip in the scatter add a purple bullet and the name of the serie and this is NOT defined in the pointFormat.

Comment: Forgive me, but I think I'm still lost, but you can edit it the same way as for boxplot from the options for tooltip:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zm10xLfr/
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.scatter.tooltip
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.scatter.tooltip.pointFormat

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution of my issue, thanx to @madepiet for the clue. The point was to set an empty headerFormat in order to remove the name of the serie automaticaly set.

I used a "for loop" in order to set tooltip for the boxplot because the lapply (first madepiet's answer) throw an error for me.

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)
library(gapminder)

ds <- gapminder %>%
  dplyr::filter(year == 2007) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(-pop)

continent_colors <- c("red", "green","yellow", "pink","blue")    

myboxplotData <- data_to_boxplot(
  ds,
  lifeExp,
  continent,
  group_var     = continent,
  add_outliers  = FALSE,
  fillColor     = continent_colors,
  color         = "black"                        
)

mylist <- list()
for (tmp in myboxplotData$data) {
  name <- tmp[[1]]$name
  high <- tmp[[1]]$high
  low <- tmp[[1]]$low
  lst <- list(
    headerFormat = '',
    pointFormat = paste0('<strong>Continent : ', name,'<br/>Maximum : ',     high,'<br/>Minimum : ', low, '</strong>')
  )    
  mylist <- append(mylist, list(lst))
}
myboxplotData$tooltip <- mylist

highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(
    events = list(
      load = JS("function () {
        Highcharts.each(this.series, function (series) {
          series.legendSymbol.attr({ fill: series.options.fillColor });
        });
      }")
    )
  ) %>%
  hc_xAxis(type ="category") %>%
  hc_add_series_list(myboxplotData) %>%
  hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "continent")) %>%
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Life expectancy")) %>%
  hc_title(text= "Boxplot using highcharter") %>% 
  hc_legend(enabled= TRUE) %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data = ds,
    type = "scatter",
    hcaes(x = "continent", y = "lifeExp", group = "continent"),
    color=continent_colors,
    tooltip = list(headerFormat="", pointFormat = "Life Expectancy: {point.y}")
  ) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(scatter = list(
    showInLegend = FALSE,
      marker = list(
      radius = 6,
      symbol = "circle",
      lineWidth = 2
    )
  )) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(scatter = list(jitter = list(x = 0.05, y = 0)))
```